# How to insert multiple records using XML in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml

i use SQL server 2008 in my web application back end. Apparently i iterate through all the records from the C# code whenever there is a multiple insertion scenario. i have never tried the multple insertion using XML. And i think after reading many blogs about XML manipulation using SQL server 2008 the process is pretty tideous ..
So my question is..

- Is Insertion via XML much efficient than the traditional insertion?
- Is the a generic way in which i can serialize a class in C# --> Manipulate XML in SQL -->Insert also Read data as XML--> Deserialize XML to usual object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole "inserting multiple records with XML" has pretty much been superseded by [table parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) in SQL Server 2008.

And mentioned in [Erland Erland Sommarskog's Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#TVP_in_TSQL): *the* definitive article on this subject.

.net has better XML handling than the SQLXML implementation too.

Comment: Thaks for the perfect answer...

Answer (score 4):

While TVPs would be a better solution, this can be done via XML as well.  I talked about it a while back in an [article and my blog](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/back-to-basics-getting-data-from-an-xml-document/).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) instead.