# 1000's of SQL Update Statements taking forever to complete

Tags: sql-server

I have to update stock prices in Pastel Evolution and need to create the update statements in C#, then execute the in SQL Server.

Each update statement looks like this..

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.fExclPrice = 521.95, t1.fInclPrice = 1 
FROM dbo._evPriceListPrices AS t1 
INNER JOIN dbo.StkItem AS t2 ON t1.iStockID = t2.StockLink 
WHERE t2.Code = '108085R' 
AND t1.iPriceListNameID = 1 AND t1.iWareHouseID = 5;
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that there are more than 14000 update statements to execute in the batch and it takes forever.

Is there a way I can speed this up?

Here is my Estimated Execution Plan.

[image: Estimated ExecutionPlan]

I could not add my Trace result here as it's too large :(

Comment: Are you doing them one by one (RBAR) or are you doing this 1000 at a time?

Comment: 14000 + at a time :(

Comment: can you make smaller batches?

Comment: I'm considering smaller batches, maybe 1000 at a time. Just trying to find out if there is a way to speed this process up by doing them all at once.

Comment: Try doing smaller batches & check the waits on the query when they are executing. Are you hitting the right indexes etc. Can you give me the plan of this query?

Comment: Is there a lot of blocking? can you run [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/docs/19_whyblocked/)?

Comment: @StijnWynants I'll get a trace and add it to my question. Working on it.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik when I run EXEC sp_WhoIsActive  I get an Stored pricedure not found error

Comment: Yeah, I linked you to the website you need to download it from. It's not a built in tool.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I'm not able to install add-on's to my clients database. They have a DB admin who handles that stuff and they are a different company. So need to works this without installing or changing anything to SQL server unfortunately :(

Comment: Use sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks in join with sys.dm_exec_sessions to find out the waits of your query

Comment: are you doing the 14,000 per batch in a single transaction or 14K transactions?

Comment: @MartinSmith I am doing 14,000 per batch in a single transaction. Basically concatenating the SQL in my question x 14,000.

Comment: That doesn't mean they are in a single transaction. Are you opening and closing the transaction explicitly?

Comment: @MartinSmith I see what you mean. I'm not using 'Begin Transaction End Transaction' at all. Just simply concatenating the above SQL and sending it to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opted to process the SQL statements in batches. Each batch has a file size of up to 500kb. This is the most I could process as the server memory is at 98%, which impacts the number of statements I can run at a time.

After doing them in batches, I found that the updates complete in 1 hour. This is a dramatic drop in time from previous methods of updating. I was using the Pastel Evolution SDK before committing raw SQL.

This still was not fast enough for me.

I then decided to add a checkbox to allow the user to select which stock items they would like to update. This will fetch and updated selected stock items only, instead of updating the entire stock table.

At the end, it comes down to CPU Memory available. If you have enough memory, then you can process larger batches. Otherwise it would be better to update records that are marked for updating only.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your query so it isn't overwriting values with the same value.
It will reduce logging.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.fExclPrice = 521.95, t1.fInclPrice = 1 
FROM dbo._evPriceListPrices AS t1 
INNER JOIN dbo.StkItem AS t2 ON t1.iStockID = t2.StockLink 
WHERE t2.Code = '108085R' 
AND t1.iPriceListNameID = 1 AND t1.iWareHouseID = 5
--Dont overwrite records with the same values it generates extra logging
AND 
(
    t1.fExclPrice IS NULL
    OR t1.fExclPrice <> 521.95
    OR t1.fInclPrice IS NULL 
    OR t1.fInclPrice <> 1
)
```

Comment: Gong to give this a try..

Comment: That's usually not necessary.  See this blog post from Paul White "The Impact of Non-Updating Updates " http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for the info. I've read this article https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114360/update-performance-where-no-data-changes which summarizes the article you referenced    and have decided to keep my non-update updates.

Answer (score 1):

insert your new prices into a temporary table

update the temp table from `dbo.StkItem` so that it has `StockLink`

the update `dbo._evPriceListPrices` from the temp table using a join on Stocklink

experiment with batch sizes 1000 might be faster or 100000 it depends on your server and the workload.

Comment: This could have been an option if the tables were in the same database. Unfortunately we are updating prices from 1 application to another, hence 1 database to another.