# Cancel update if no columns changed

Tags: sql-server

How could SP be modified the way it will execute `update` only in case any updated value is different?

Assume we have a table

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    StudentId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(255) NULL    
 )
```

```
|----|------|
| Id | Name |
|----|------|
| 1  | Jane |
|----|------|
| 2  | John |
|----|------|
| 3  | NULL |
|----|------|
```

and the single student update stored procedure

```
[dbo].[student_update] (@StudentId int, @Name nvarchar(255)) AS
update [dbo].[students]
set [Name] = @Name
where [StudentId] = @StudentId
```

So again, how this could SP be modified the way it will execute `update` only in case `@Name` does not equal to `[Name]`?

Please take into account that `[Name]` could be `NULL`

```
DECLARE @areFieldsDifferent = CASE WHEN (
([NAME] is null and  @Name is not null) OR
([NAME] is not null and  @Name is null) OR
([NAME] <> @Name)
)
then 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

But how could be compared `@Name` with `[Name]` from `Select * From Students where StudentId = @StudentId`?
And how to use it to not call `update` statement?

Comment: Logically speaking, the column Name should not be nullable. Fix that and part of your issue evaporates. Natural key enforcement is always required - an identity column does not relieve you of that responsibility.

Comment: This answer may add details about what you're looking for https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your conditions in the WHERE clause:

```
update 
    [dbo].[students]
set 
    [Name] = @Name
where 
    [StudentId] = @StudentId
    and 
    -- add your conditions here
    ([Name] <> @Name 
     or ([Name] is null and @Name is not null)
     or ([Name] is not null and @Name is null))
```